# Regex crashes due to some reason

Tags: regex

I have worked so little on regular expressions. So take me a newbie for this question as I am learning it.

I have made a regular expression to get particular web urls from a list of urls.

**Here is the list:**

```
http://www.xxxx.com/us/en/brothers---sisters/one/maria-lang-1-c671030p2313063.html
http://www.xxxx.com/us/en/lookbook-c471503.html
http://www.xxxx.com/us/en/pictures-c496502.html
http://www.xxxx.com/us/en/woman/shoes/high-heels-c269195.html
http://www.xxxx.com/us/en/woman/handbags-c269200.html
http://www.xxxx.com/us/en/woman/handbags/messenger-bags-c269202.html
```

**My Regex:**

```
(us\/en\/)^(lookbook)|^(brothers---sisters)|^(pictures)[a-z0-9\-\/]*(c\d+(p\d+)?).html
```

**I don't want to:** extract first three urls only but this regex crashes when I test it on an online tester. Although, I have come to know that when I remove the first '^' operator from the regex. It at least runs without crash but of course I don't get relevant results.

Comment: There's something wrong here, `^` denotes start of the line, you can't use it in middle of a match. Without it your regex is correct, see http://regex101.com/r/gU3aB5/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misplaced the caret `^`, use this:

```
(us\/en\/)(lookbook|brothers---sisters|pictures[a-z0-9\-\/]*c\d+(p\d+)?\.html)
```

**Edit according to comment:**

Use a negative look ahead to match url but the first 3:

```
(us\/en\/)(?!lookbook|brothers---sisters|pictures[a-z0-9\-\/]*c\d+(p\d+)?\.html)
```

Comment: I am really sorry I made a mistake.
I said, "I want to get first three urls"
I needed to say , "I *don't* want to get first three urls." that's why I user the caret sign that is used as not.
Sorry for that, I am editing the question.